# How can I get the JWT token after authenticating?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt

I have a Rest spring-boot API that when a user authenticates the api returns the token jwt, I noticed in the browser that the token appears in the Response Header> Authentication and in the tests with the Postman it shows in the Body.

How can I get this token to store in the Local Storage browser by Reactjs?

My code that makes the requests looks like this:

```
import { ACCESS_TOKEN, API_BASE_URL } from '../constants';

export function request (options) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
        headers.append('Authorzation', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN))
    }
    return fetch(API_BASE_URL+options.url, {
        method: options.method,
        headers: headers,
        body: options.body
    })
    .then(function(response){ 
        // Falta pegar o token e gravar na local estorage
        if (!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(json);
        }
        return json;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

// Save data to the current local store

```
 localStorage.setItem("username", "John");
```

// Access some stored data

```
alert( "username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));
```

The first argument of setitem is the key

My account got blocked by some down votes questions, the funny thing is I have to re-edit them, even though I already have the accepted answer.I do not understand what's the point to do this.I am so frustrated by this stackoverflow system.

Now, I basically can do nothing but keep editing my questions, and they have all been answered. This is ridiculous !!!

Comment: **"How can I get this token..."** My main doubt is how to get the token! Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @user2831852 you need to set the token first, how can you get it if you don't it in your browser?

Comment: @user2831852 when you use JWT generate the token, you need to pass it to the browser, then you can get it.